# KitchenAid Freezer not cold enough

Tags: refrigerator, freezer

KitchenAid KSSC48QTS01 Side-by-side Built-in Refrigerator
Freezer is not getting colder than 22 degrees F for several days. Problem began after freezer door was left slightly ajar overnight.
My inspection reveals: Condenser fan is running. I cleaned the condenser coils. Evaporator fan is running. No ice buildup noted on evaporator coils. Temperature is set to "Max Cool" -5 F/34 F (freezer/fridge). Refrigerator temperature is at desired temp of 34-37F.
I placed a wireless thermometer in the freezer. It shows temperature increases every 8 hours as expected for defrost cycle, then drops down, but plateaus between 22 and 25 degrees. Never gets below 20 degrees. (I will try to attach an image of the freezer temperature graph)[image]
What is wrong with my refrigerator?

Comment: Could be your compressor is low on refrigerant, or your condenser coils are dirty (prevents heat transfer to the air).

Comment: Has this question been abandoned?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the defrost cycle isn't long enough to clear out all the frost and the ice is blocking the flow of cold air to the interior of the freezer compartment, or ice that may be plugging the defrost melt drain line and not allowing water out during the defrost cycle (which freezes again after the defrost cycle and adds to the blockage problem.)

Sometimes if you can remove the interior back panel (or floor panel) of the freezer compartment, you can get to the ice that's causing problems.

Make arrangements for the food. Unplug or turn off the freezer for 24-36 hours or so and then start it back up. That should give the ice enough opportunity to fully melt off and allow the blockage to clear. If you can find where the ice is, you can help it melt with a turkey baster and some warm water.